# One select * and one select 1 with union select sql

Tags: mysql

I want to create Sql query like below:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `post_sale` 
WHERE   id = 820705 
UNION 
SELECT  id 
INTO    OUTFILE 'C:/xampp/htdocs/ttv.php' 
FROM    post_sale
```

But it says error like The used `SELECT` statements have a different number of columns..
My problem is I want to select * from first statement and only select one from second union select state..

Any helps!

Comment: Then for the 2nd query just use select `id, "" as col2,"" as col3,...` which fill the missing columns with null or something

Comment: in order to union both select statement should have same number of columns same order and should be compatible by datatype

Comment: what db are you using? mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 1):

`a UNION ALL b` requests two result sets and concatenates their rows. `UNION` does the same thing, but removes rows that are duplicated in the result sets. For this to work, the result sets `a` and `b` must have the same number of columns, and the columns have to be the same type or implicitly castable to the same type.

So, `SELECT * FROM table UNION SELECT val` makes no sense.

Also, `SELECT id` makes no sense unless you add a `FROM` clause telling where to find this `id` column

It's possible you want a result set with an extra COLUMN, like this

```
 SELECT *, id FROM post_sale WHERE id = constant
```

That combines the data items you want into a particular row. It's not a UNION but it may do what you want.